# Is it possible to sort indexedDB result set without temp array i.e. by using db queries

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

Is it possible to sort the result set produced by indexedDB without using push
operation in the temporary array.So that no manual looping is involved.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases this is possible using indexes. For example, if you have records of the form `{team_id: 123, name: 'alice'}` and wanted to select by team_id then sort by name you could construct an index on `[team_id, name]`, and call `openCursor()` (or `getAll()` if supported) with a key range `IDBKeyRange.bound([id], [id+1], false, true)` to get all records with team_id == id and sorted by name.

If you can't construct an index for this - e.g. if the sort comparison function you want doesn't match IDB key ordering, or if your selection can't be expressed simply as a range - then you'll need to use a temp array.